# Complex cardiac surgery story

Tags: technique, plot, publishing, short-story

I will be writing a short story with the title as "Complex cardiac surgery".

Can this story written later converted to a documentary movie with the end user audience as MBBS (Medical) students?

Comment: I am confused by your question.  When one writes a "short story", it is often fiction.  When one films a "documentary movie", there is an expectation of filming real events as they happen rather than filming actors performing based on a script.  Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks. This is a non fiction story. Documentary movie created on this non fiction story where the end user audience are Medical students studying in medical colleges.

Comment: Please can you give some more details about your story? Are you describing details of anatomy, incisions, thought processes etc as the surgery takes place or is it about pre and post op decisions, emotions etc? Are you the surgeon talking about your own experiences?

Comment: Story features : 1 Patient suffering from a cardiac ailment. 2 Patient's brother-in- law finding the Best cardiac surgeon in the healthcare sector to perform a complex cardiac surgery 3 The Cardiac surgeon successfully performs the open heart bypass surgery and shares his success with the complexity faced. Note: This is a non fiction story.

Comment: NB You can edit the question to add the summary of the story (and any future clarifications), that way people won't have to look through the comments to find it. -- Is there a reason why you expect it might be difficult to convert it to a documentary? Because I'm assuming you'd like more from the answer than just a confirmation that yes, you can (probably) turn it into a documentary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Probably more suitable for a lay audience

I have substantial experience of developing learning materials for surgeons and students.

From the little information you have provided, what you are proposing seems to fit better into a general interest category for the public. You don’t say where you are based, but in the UK there’s certainly an audience for medical documentaries that combine human interest with medical details, e.g. The Surgeon’s Cut (Netflix), Super Surgeons (Channel 4), 24 hours in A&E (Channel 4). You might want to look at what’s already out there and see if that's the kind of thing you are thinking about.

When medical educators develop learning materials, we usually do so with a specific purpose. For example, if we want to teach how to do a procedure, we might film a simulation of the procedure on a donated cadaver, showing every incision, every clamp. Perhaps in tandem, we might obtain permission to use footage of the actual operation from a surgeon’s headcam, so that the student can then see what it looks like on a living body. As part of teaching professional skills, we might film a simulated discussion between a surgeon and a patient’s family, where they have to impart difficult news. It tends to be much more focused and detailed than what you appear to be suggesting.

What do you think medical students will gain from watching your story? If you are thinking about partnering with a medical teaching institution, they will want to know what the learning outcomes are and how it fits into their curriculum. They also have limited pots of money and are often stretched to supply the basics, so any film would have to offer superlative educational benefits for them to even consider it.

To give an example, I was approached by a surgeon who wanted to make a 360 degree film of a particular procedure in simulation. The plus points are that it is very difficult to get live footage of that particular procedure and so far there are no realistic simulations (fulfils a need), the procedure itself does not take long (reduces filming costs), the procedure is life-saving (benefit to patient care if surgeons are trained better), it would be seen from multiple perspectives (increased audience of entire surgical team), and we cover that procedure on one of our courses (fits with curriculum). However, although it’s a fantastic idea, we are still only considering it, because there is so much work and cost involved, it might not be practical.

I can't say you *won't* have an audience of medical students if you managed to make your film - they might watch with passing interest, in the same way that they might watch any medical documentary. However, I think it's unlikely that you could get medical schools interested. Whether there is another potential audience will depend on the commercial marketability of your story.